# meter un ArrayList un array

Tags: java

Tengo una duda acerca de los ArrayList.

Lo que quiero hacer es meter un array dentro de un ArrayList.

Tengo una clase paciente con los atributos:

```
public class Paciente extends Persona {
private String grupoSanguineo; 
private ArrayList<String> medicamentosAlergia;
.
.
```

y un contructor:

```
public Paciente(String DNI, String NSS, String nombre, String apellido, String direccion,String grupoSanguineo){
    super(DNI,NSS,nombre,apellido,direccion);
    this.grupoSanguineo=grupoSanguineo;
}
```

Me piden: Implementa otro constructor de la clase Paciente, que además de los parámetros definidos en el anterior constructor, reciba un array de Strings. El constructor se encargará de incluir en su ArrayList “medicamentosAlergia” cada uno de los Strings contenidos en el array.
Recuerda que este último parámetro lo podemos instanciar en la propia llamada al constructor así:   new String[]{"Ibuprofeno","Amoxicilina"}

lo que yo he hecho es esto pero me da error

```
public Paciente(String DNI, String NSS, String nombre, String apellido, String direccion,String grupoSanguineo, String[]medicamento){
super(DNI,NSS,nombre,apellido,direccion);
   medicamentosAlergia= new String []{"Ibuprofeno","Amoxicilina"};

}
```

Alguien me podría orientar como puedo hacerlo, lo he intentado todo y no me sale. Soy nueva en esto.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te confundes,

lo que te piden es que pases, como parámetro de entrada en la llamada al constructor de Paciente, la siguiente línea:

```
new String []{"Ibuprofeno","Amoxicilina"}
```

De esta forma la nueva instancia incorporará alergias a los medicamentos incluidos en el String Array.

En tu constructor de Paciente debes agregar el código necesario para gestionar este array de Strings e incorporarlo a tus medicamentosAlergia.

Podría ser algo así:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Paciente extends Persona {
    private String grupoSanguineo; 
    private ArrayList<String> medicamentosAlergia;

    public Paciente(String DNI, String NSS, String nombre, String apellido, String direccion,String grupoSanguineo){

        super(DNI,NSS,nombre,apellido,direccion);
        this.grupoSanguineo = grupoSanguineo;    
        //Inicializamos para evitar acceso a atributos nulos
        medicamentosAlergia= new ArrayList<String>();
     }

    public Paciente(String DNI, String NSS, String nombre, String apellido, String direccion,String grupoSanguineo, String[] medicamentos){

       this(DNI,NSS,nombre,apellido,direccion,grupoSanguineo);
       for(String medicamento : medicamentos)
       {
          this.medicamentosAlergia.add(medicamento);
       }
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Paciente [grupoSanguineo=" + grupoSanguineo + ", medicamentosAlergia=" + medicamentosAlergia
                + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }



    public static void main (String [ ] args) {
        Paciente pacienteSinAlergias = new Paciente("0000","00000","Alberto","Sanchez","direccion1","B");   
        Paciente pacienteConAlergias = new Paciente("0000","00000","Alberto","Sanchez","direccion1","B", new String[]{"Ibuprofeno","Amoxicilina"});

        System.out.println(pacienteSinAlergias.toString());
        System.out.println(pacienteConAlergias.toString());

    }

}
```

En el main puedes ver un ejemplo de test.

Saludos.

Comment: Le piden que implemente otro constructor, no que sustituya el existente. Tu código sustituye el existente, mete a la clase otro constructor para que no sustituya al existente, lo demás está perfecto.

Comment: @chikebox estás en lo cierto. Edito.